# Force a UAC Prompt to Change Screensaver Settings

Tags: windows-7, windows, uac, screensaver

I want to force a UAC whenever someone goes to change the screensaver settings. I already did a registry hack where it forces the user to put in the admin password whenever the UAC pops up. Now I want the same so that the user can't change the amount of time that it takes for the screensaver to kick in, or not let them take out the checkmark that locks the computer when the screensaver kicks in.

I'm guessing I would need a registry hack that elevates permission for the Personalization settings.

Comment: this on a domain?

Comment: I don't know about invoking a UAC prompt, but you can use group policy to restrict them from changing the screen saver settings.

Comment: What would be the registry hack for it? It's not Windows 7 professional, I don't have have the group policy editor available.

Comment: @threehappypenguins What about [preventing the screen saver dialog from opening](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#96)?

Comment: I would really prefer to have some way to simply have the UAC pop up. I don't want to disable the changing on the screensaver, I just don't want unauthorized change of the screensaver. But if someone would explain to me the registry hack to restrict the screen saver settings, or even preventing the screensaver dialog from opening, then fine. If someone would please just explain how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal, but I followed and31415's link here: http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#96

Anytime I want to change the screensaver settings myself, I will have to disable the registry hack, and then enable it again when done. But, oh well. At least now others will not be able to change the screen saver to 1000 minutes or whatever to prevent the lock screen when the computer is not in use.